# How to replicate this query in Crystal Reports with group bys?

Tags: group-by, crystal-reports

I am attempting to achieve the top result (4 rows) through a Crystal report, but can't figure out the group bys in Crystal. The bottom table is wrong since it adds freight to each subtotal. the freight should only be added once since its the same order.

I've attempted the below group bys through Group Expert but only one row shows up.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Group by Customer# and on GroupExpert instead of -A ( in asceding order) choose -O (Original Order)